# Image differences detection in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure, correlation

I'm trying to find the broken ligaments for these two photos. Because the patten it got I can use the conv2 function find the general broken areas. However, it is really hard for me think how to make it tell the exact broken ligaments. Can you guys give me some idea for how to find which ligaments are broken please?

Because I'm new to this website, I can not post more photos with 2-D convolution results.

## Original Picture

[image: original pictures]

## Broken Picture

[image: Broken one]

Comment: detect edges, followed by hough lines for straight line detection. from here you will compare the straight lines in the broken images to your straight lines in the non-broken image

Comment: @ABC Hi the hough lines I got are tangled or something. It can not generate whole straight line. Do you have recommendation for that? I used polar format

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about- perhaps you did not zoom in enough? Matlab often shows lines as broken or bent when they're actually not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img = imread('unbroke.jpg');
level = graythresh(rgb2gray(img));
BW = im2bw(rgb2gray(img),level);
BW2= imdilate(imerode(BW, ones(5)), ones(5)); 
BW3 = bwmorph(BW2,'remove');
figure, imshow(BW2), hold on[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[H,T,R] = hough(BW2);
P  = houghpeaks(H,15,'threshold',ceil(0.3*max(H(:))));
x = T(P(:,2)); y = R(P(:,1));
lines = houghlines(BW2,T,R,P,'FillGap',5,'MinLength',7);

max_len = 0;
for k = 1:length(lines)
   xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
   plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');

   % Plot beginnings and ends of lines
   plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
   plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');

   % Determine the endpoints of the longest line segment
   len = norm(lines(k).point1 - lines(k).point2);
   if ( len > max_len)
      max_len = len;
      xy_long = xy;
   end
end
```

lines from unbroken image

[image]

lines from broken image

[image]

Now, you know what the line segments are do some matching. Or else find pairs of segments that would be connected (same slope + same x/y intercept) within a threshold.

Answer (score 1):

Make a region growing algorithm inside each perfect square.
Once you get that, calculate the area of that section.

Once you find this, calculate the remaining areas. The larger values will be the broken ligaments :)

Comment: Hi I can find the area for each small shape by imfill function is it what you mean? thanks

Comment: Yes exactly. You know from the other "perfect" image what is the area more or less of each square. Therefore, comparing the areas between the perfect ones and the new ones that you get, any "major" difference will be classified as a broken square.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an interesting way to do this too. I saved the second image only as 'image.jpg'.

```
I = imread('image.jpg');
J = imbinarize(rgb2gray(I)); % Threshold to get a BW image.
BW = bwpropfilt(~J, 'Area', [35001, 1013283]);
imshow(BW)
```

shows

[image: Broken Edges filtered]

For selecting the area thresholds easily, I used https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/calculate-region-properties-using-image-region-analyzer.html

If you don't have a recent MATLAB version where `imbinarize` or `bwpropfilt` doesn't exist, you can use equivalent thresholding functions, and `regionprops` to extract all objects within the area range.